# Remotely adding printer with batch file ; 0x32 This operation is not supported

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line, printing, rundll32

I am trying to add a network printer via batch file, provided I feed the data(Printer IP, Printer Name, Computer IP) into the entries.

```
rundll32 printui.dll,PrintUIEntry /if /b "KONICA MINOLTA C451 PS(P)" /c\\%computerNameIP% /h "x86" /f %windir%\inf\prnkm002.inf /r "IP_%computerNameIP%" /m "KONICA MINOLTA C451 PS(P)" /n\\%computerNameIP%\%printerName%   /F %windir%\inf\prnkm002.inf
```

Now, once this command is completed, I receive the following error:

Operation could not be completed(error 0x00000032). This operation is not supported.

I ran a similar code with runs the GUI:

```
rundll32 printui.dll,PrintUIEntry /il /b "KONICA MINOLTA C451 PS(P)" /c\\%computerNameIP% /h "x86" /f %windir%\inf\prnkm002.inf /r "IP_%computerNameIP%" /m "KONICA MINOLTA C451 PS(P)" /n\\%computerNameIP% \%printerName%   /F %windir%\inf\prnkm002.inf
```

and I have to choose a local [local Printer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/klzJv.png): which I adjust to be TCP/IP and the drivers come default since I set it. After choosing my driver, I receive the error as well.

I just can't pinpoint what exactly isn't supported.

Windows 7 32-bit. I made adjustments to the registry, print management, group policy, but none of those seem concrete to what is preventing a remote add to a network printer.

Comment: What is `\%printerName%`? Is that supposed to be part of `/n`?  Can you post the entire batch file? or at least the variable declarations?

Comment: %printerName% - declares what the displayed printer name is. When I have been testing it, I just give it the same exact name as the model, to make sure there isn't any issues with the naming scheme.

Comment: My point is that it's kind of just hanging there.  `/n\\%computerNameIP% ^ \%printerName`.  If you're trying to *name* it "\\192.168.1.50\Printer01" then it should be `/n \\%computerNameIP%\%printerName%`

Comment: https://www.scribd.com/document/326412219/Printer-Test - Batch file. I am specifically doing just:
IP of printer, Y, Y, Name I give printer, IP of computer.

Comment: My bad, I added a bunch of ^ to make the code viewable up above. I'll adjust the doc.

Comment: The code is how you wrote it, I just adjusted it to make it look nicer on this website. The actual code does not have the ^ in it.

Comment: I see 3 variants of the command in the bat file, are any of them successful?

Comment: Everything is run local in the other parts. I don't run it, since I still have to edit that code- but its safe to say it isn't run.

Comment: If the printer name has spaces you'll need to change the `/n` parameters to `/n "\\%computerNameIP%\%printerName%"`

Comment: I've been naming them test_print1....test_print20

Comment: Any thoughts @Scott

Comment: No, sorry. It's almost impossible to duplicate without a network printer and valid INF file.  I tried a few things including generic printers and my PDF writer but the command always said it couldn't find an appropriate driver.  Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I found another way to do it with the prncnfg.vbs files. First create the port, assign it, then manage it.

This is all located in the admin scripts in Windows folder